# Solve the ode using fixed-point iteration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, finite-differences

I have the following equation

$-[(1+u^{4})u_x]_x = sin(x)+sin(5x)$, where the domain is $[0,2\pi]$

$u(0)=u(2\pi)=0$ for boundaries.

How to find a numerical solution for $u$ using numerical method?

My idea is to replace all the derivatives with fixed-point approximation, and then do some iterations until convergence.
But I'm stuck with the differentiation approximation vector...

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just solve it directly? \begin{align} - [(1+u^{4})u_{x}]_{x} &= \sin x + \sin 5x \\ \implies - [(1+u^{4})u_{x}] &= - \cos x - \frac{\cos 5x}{5} + C_{1} \\ \implies -u - \frac{u^{5}}{5} &= - \sin x - \frac{\sin 5x}{25} + C_{1} x + C_{2} \end{align}

Comment: @mattos thanks, I just want to explore about the finite difference approach.

Comment: For numerical solutions, you should either specify some initial or boundary conditions (to (hopefully) pick out a unique solution) or specify a range of such values (to iterate over to understand how the solution depends on these conditions).  Otherwise, how can your numerical method do something sensible with your two constants of integration?

Comment: @EricTowers Thanks, I forgot to add it on the question body

Comment: Perhaps you mean you are stuck for your **initial** approximation vector.  Not entirely uncommon choices are $1$, the right-hand side (the inhomogeneous part of) the equation, or a simple polynomial that matches the boundary conditions, for example $x(2\pi - x)$.

Comment: @TIANBAI Fair enough. Just so you know, in case you don't find a solution to your problem here, there is a stackexchange site dedicated to scientific computing over at [scicomp.stackexchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The equation can be written in the form
$$
(1+u^4)u_{xx} + 4 u^3 (u_x)^2 = f(x).
$$

Using centred finite differences, we get
$$
(1+u_i^4)(u_{i+1}-2u_i+u_{i-1}) + u_i^3 (u_{i+1}-u_{i-1})^2 = h^2 f_i.
$$

Finally, you must solve this nonlinear system using a fixed point method. One possibility could be

$$
u_i^{(k+1)}=\frac{u_{i+1}^{(k)}+u_{i-1}^{(k)}}{2}+\frac{(u_i^{(k)})^3(u_{i+1}^{(k)}-u_{i-1}^{(k)})^2}{2(1+(u_{i}^{(k)})^4)}-\frac{h^2 f_i}{2(1+(u_i^{(k)})^4)}
$$

Now, you need to check if it converges and, if it does not converge, rewrite the nonlinear system into another fixed point problem.